# How to make all of my for loop runs at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, wxpython, ipython

I have few for loop that will flash objects for 5 seconds with 0.5 seconds interval. And I am trying to figure out how to make all these object to flash at the same time, in other words, I want to run all the for loops at the same time.

Need help!

```
        count1=5

        for k in range (count1):
            error.setFill('grey')
            time.sleep(.50)
            error.setFill('orange')
            time.sleep(.50)

        for l in range (count1):              
            go.setFill('red')
            time.sleep(.50)
            go.setFill('green')
            time.sleep(.50)

        for m in range (count1):               
            warning.setFill('black')
            time.sleep(.50)
            warning.setFill('red')
            time.sleep(.50)

        for u in range (count1):
            Verify.setFill('green')
            time.sleep(.50)
            Verify.setFill('grey')
            time.sleep(.50)

        for w in range (count1):
            Launch.setFill('red')
            time.sleep(.50)
            Launch.setFill('green')
            time.sleep(.50)
```

Comment: Use threading module

Comment: No, this question is tagged `wxpython`, so the GUI toolkit and its event system should be utilized to do timer related tasks. No sleep(), no multiple threads, no multiple processes.

Comment: @blubberdiblub I agree. Either combine the loops into a single loop as suggested by answers VMRuiz and Charlie or fire up wx.Timer() commands with 500 millisecond intervals for each one

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to do it, supposing that `setFill()` is fast enough so they appear to be turning on and off at the same time.

```
count1=5

for k in range (count1):
    # Turn on
    error.setFill('grey')
    go.setFill('red')
    warning.setFill('black')
    Verify.setFill('green')
    Launch.setFill('red')
    time.sleep(.50)
    # Turn off
    error.setFill('orange')
    go.setFill('green')
    warning.setFill('red')
    Verify.setFill('grey')
    Launch.setFill('green')
    time.sleep(.50)
```

In another case, you will need the create a new thread for each light.

Comment: @Nina if one of these answers, answers your question please accept it by clicking the accept button. If either was helpful, click the useful Up arrow

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as all your loops are all running in the range of `count1`, why not run all commands in the same loop, for example:

```
    count1=5

    for n in range (count1):
    # first line of each loop
        error.setFill('grey')
        go.setFill('red')
        warning.setFill('black')
        Verify.setFill('green')
        Launch.setFill('red')
    # pause and then third line of each loop
        time.sleep(.50) 
        error.setFill('orange')
        go.setFill('green')         
        warning.setFill('red')
        Verify.setFill('grey')
        Launch.setFill('green')
        time.sleep(.50)
```

This is then running all your loops at once, or rather in the same loop, and it takes less effort and typing. Hope that helps!